# Can I add a title to gallery?

Tags: android, textview, gallery, title

Is it possible to add a title (maybe textView) to a gallery?

(I know how to add textView to each item in gallery using adapter but looking for a title to all the gallery)

In more details:

I have a listView and I'm using ListAdapter to set him.

The return value of getView() of this listAdapter is gallery Object.

And i want this gallery to have a title

Comment: Add one TextView in your layout above the gallery

Comment: Title to all the gallery? means how many gallery are there ?

Comment: I have a ListView of Galleries. And I need a title to each gallery that can set according to the gallery content. I dont want to add new ListItem for each gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, instead, use a vertical `LinearLayout` in which you have, first, a `TextView` for the title, then the `Gallery`? Then you can listen for selected item changed event and change title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

yes, just add a text view to your main layout outside of GalleryView.

Set OnItemSelectedListener on GalleryVIew. in onItemSelected, set title's text according to the position of imageview in gallery.

Comment: Is it possible to add a title within the gallery and not in textView above it?